# USB Driver Compilation Error

Tags: c, linux, compilation, usb, drivers

I'm currently trying to compile a Linux USB UART driver, which is provided here:
http://www.exar.com/connectivity/uart-and-bridging-solutions/usb-uarts/xr21v1410

The driver consists of 2 header files and one large C file. These are the contents of the Makefile:

```
obj-m := vizzini.o

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD       := $(shell pwd)

EXTRA_CFLAGS    := -DDEBUG=0

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD)

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions vtty
```

This is the error the compiler is throwing when I run make:

```
[sj755@localhost xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak]$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.4.9-2.fc16.x86_64/build M=/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.4.9-2.fc16.x86_64'
  LD      /home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.o
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1643:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1643:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘vizzini_device.ioctl’) [enabled by default]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1646:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1646:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘vizzini_device.tiocmget’) [enabled by default]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1647:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1647:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘vizzini_device.tiocmset’) [enabled by default]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c: In function ‘vizzini_init’:
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1663:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_serial_register’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1677:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_serial_deregister’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c: In function ‘__check_debug’:
/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.c:1698:83: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak/vizzini.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/sj755/Downloads/xr21v141x-lnx-2.6.35-pak] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.4.9-2.fc16.x86_64'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These are the headers included in the main c source file:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/tty_flip.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usb/serial.h>
#include <linux/serial.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/unaligned.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

#include <linux/usb/cdc.h>
#ifndef CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_TYPE
#define CDC_DATA_INTERFACE_TYPE 0x0a
#endif
#ifndef USB_RT_ACM
#define USB_RT_ACM      (USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_RECIP_INTERFACE)
#define ACM_CTRL_DTR            0x01
#define ACM_CTRL_RTS            0x02
#define ACM_CTRL_DCD            0x01
#define ACM_CTRL_DSR            0x02
#define ACM_CTRL_BRK            0x04
#define ACM_CTRL_RI             0x08
#define ACM_CTRL_FRAMING        0x10
#define ACM_CTRL_PARITY         0x20
#define ACM_CTRL_OVERRUN        0x40
#endif

#include "linux/version.h"

#include "vizzini.h"
```

Running Linux kernel 3.4.9-2.fc16.x86_64

I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving the errors.

**EDIT**

It seems that `usb_serial_register` and `usb_serial_deregister` were never defined in my kernel's API. However, `usb_serial_register_drivers` and `usb_serial_deregister_drivers` are. Below are the definitions:

```
int usb_serial_register(struct usb_serial_driver *driver);
void usb_serial_deregister(struct usb_serial_driver *device);
int usb_serial_register_drivers(struct usb_driver *udriver,
                                struct usb_serial_driver * const serial_drivers[]);
void usb_serial_deregister_drivers(struct usb_driver *udriver,
                                   struct usb_serial_driver * const serial_drivers[]);
```

Comment: Perhaps try `#include <linux/kref.h>` and `#include <linux/mutex.h>`? http://fossies.org/dox/ns-allinone-3.16/18_2include_2linux_2usb_2serial_8h.html

Comment: @SSHThis That's a good find, but I got same compilation error.

Comment: Does this just provide a UART? Have you tried the device with the system, without the custom driver?

Comment: @MarcButler The driver is supposed to create a tty device (ttyUSB[0-4]) when I connect the USB cable from my computer to, in my case, an FPGA board. On Windows, a new comport will appear in the device manager when I connect to my FPGA.

Comment: I think you'll find with Linux kernel that ships with a distribution that will occur anyway, as usb to serial support is pretty standard. I would suggest you plug in the device and see if ttyUSB0 pops up in `/dev`. I know this to be case as I use an rs232 to usb adapter more days than not.

Comment: @MarcButler Nothing new pops up in /dev when I connect to the USB-UART port. As a side not, I've included the documentation on the board I'm using.

Comment: @MarcButler see https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=64f0d8cd089ee7e501116181a343c3739df5fe53 for why this driver isn't in linux upstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API inside the kernel (available header files, their contents, function prototypes (or if they exist in the first place), ...) is **not** fixed (see [Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/stable_api_nonsense.txt;h=db3be892afb2b64ee582a5e43ce87223a1251ad3;hb=HEAD) in your nearest Linux source if you are curious), so a driver can typically only be compiled for a rather narrow range of kernels. Check if the source is (roughly) contemporary with the kernel.

You should also check if a driver for that has already been included in the kernel, either as an official driver or in the staging area. Look around [Linux USB](http://www.linux-usb.org/) to check for alternative drivers and other news. If nothing else helps, you should take a look at [LWN](http://lwn.net)'s kernel pages (search there for functions you can't find in the current source and discussion on replacement), probably after using something like cscope to create an index of your source (kernel and driver). Please do get in touch with the people responsible for this area, so they know you are groping around and perhaps give some pointers.

Comment: You seem to be right. I grepped for `usb_serial_register`, but no exact match came up. However, `usb_serial_register_drivers` did appear. I've updated my question to include the definitions of `usb_serial_register` (found on google) and `usb_serial_register_drivers` (found in my my /lib). Do you think `usb_serial_register_drivers` was intended to be a replacement?

Comment: As I said, check LWN's kernel page. Changes like that are normally reported there. And Linux-USB should also know.