# Silabs Usb CP210x drivers error

Tags: linux, makefile, serial-port, raspberry-pi, uart

I have a problem when I try to install a driver for my Silabs USB to UART bridge.

I downloaded the driver from here: http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx

I'm trying to install it in my raspberry which has kernel 3.6.11

In the instructions I can see the following:

```
make (your cp2010x driver)
cp cp2010x.ko to /libmodules/<kernel>/kernel/driver/usb/serial
insmod /libmodules/<kernel>/kernel/driver/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
insmod xp2010x.ko
```

However, I get this error when I try to call MAKE:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.6.11+/build M=/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux'

  CC [M]  /home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.o
/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.c:164:12: error: ´usb_serial_probe´ undeclared here (not in a function)

/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.c:165:16: error: ´usb_serial_disconnect´ undeclared here (not in a function)

/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.c: In function ´cp210x_init´:

/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.c:989:2: error: implicit declaration of function ´usb_serial_register´ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.c:996:3: error: implicit declaration of function ´usb_serial_deregister´ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

```
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1/cp210x.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/Desktop/vcp/Linux1] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Any ideas??Is there any problem with the cp210x.c file?? Unfortunately I cannot edit it!! Please help if you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the drivers that are on the Silicon Labs website are meant as an example.

The recommended path here is to go into the source for your kernel, and get the driver there. Or if you can do a 'make menuconfig' you can add in the CP210x USB Serial driver for your distribution. As of 3.x the kernel is up to date and maintained for proper serial communication for all CP210x devices.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is related to this post: [USB Driver Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408930/usb-driver-compilation-error)

The USB serial driver API appears to have changed in the linux kernel, and the silabs driver that you are compiling is meant for the older kernels. There are some data structures that have changed, so I believe the silab driver has to be modified in order for it to work on linux 3.6.x and above.

Have you made any progress since posting this question?